# Linear combination of linear mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The problem:

Determine the linear combinations $ \varphi ,\psi: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ of linear mapping.

$ 2 \varphi + 3 \psi $, where $m=3,n=2$ and $\varphi(x,y,z) \rightarrow(-x+6y,2z), \psi$ is the orthogonal projection to the plane of $x,y$ axes.

"My solution":

I see that, $ 2 \varphi + 3 \psi :\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$

And I can write that, $(x,y,z)(2 \varphi + 3 \psi)=2\cdot(x,y,z) \varphi+3\cdot(x,y)\psi=2 \cdot(-x+6y,2z)+3(x,y)\psi $

it's not clear for me, what kind of "polynom" should I give, from the orthogonal projection to the plane of $x,y$ axes. Is my solution still good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\psi$ applies to a vector $(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3$ to give $(x,y)$ hence

$$(x,y,z)\psi=(x,y)$$
so the linear combination gives

$$(x,y,z)(2\phi+3\psi)=2(-x+6y,2z)+3(x,y)=(x+12y,4z+3y)$$